# Why does my database load fully using expo-file-system in development with Expo Go, but it doesn't fully load using TestFlight?

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight, expo-sqlite, expo-file-system

I'm creating a simple app that uses data in a preloaded database from an assets folder ("../assets/worldEnglishBible.db" (4.8 MB). I'm utilizing [expo-sqlite](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/) to query the data and [expo-file-system](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) to load the database so it can be used by expo-sqlite. The database loads and is fully accessible when tested on the Expo Go app; however, when I create a production build and run it on TestFlight the database fails to load fully (only loads 243 bytes, <1%).

Below is my code to load the database. The deleteDatabaseSQL function is used to for development, to delete the database and re-download it for testing.

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

const downloadWEB = async (setDatabaseSize, setConsoleText) => {
  const callback = (downloadProgress) => {
    console.log(downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten);
    setDatabaseSize(downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten);
  };
  //Download WEB database

  const downloadResumableWEB = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
    Asset.fromModule(require("../assets/worldEnglishBible.db")).uri,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite/worldEnglishBible.db",
    {},
    callback
  );

  try {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite"
    );
    const { uri } = await downloadResumableWEB.downloadAsync();
    console.log("Finished downloading to ", uri);
    setConsoleText("Finished downloading to " + uri);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    setConsoleText(error.message);
  }
};

const deleteDatabaseSQL = async (setDatabaseSize, setConsoleText) => {
  try {
    await FileSystem.deleteAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite");
    console.log("database deleted");
    setConsoleText("database deleted");
    setDatabaseSize(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    setConsoleText(error.message);
  } finally {
  }
};

export { downloadWEB, deleteDatabaseSQL };
```

Below is my metro.config.js file

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.resolver.assetExts.push(
  // Adds support for `.db` files for SQLite databases
  "db"
);

module.exports = config;
```

Here is a screenshot from a development screen when my app is loaded on TestFlight. The highlighted portion is an AppContext state variable consoleText, set by setConsoleText.

[Screenshot from TestFlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqUEd.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone have any help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Other code I've attempted to use from the expo-sqlite API documentation:
`
async function openDatabaseWEB() {
  try {
    if (
      !(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite"))
        .exists
    ) {
      await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
        FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite"
      );
    }
    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      Asset.fromModule(require("../assets/worldEnglishBible.db")).uri,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite/worldEnglishBible.db"
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
`